# How to get the CefSharp element's xpath with code in .NET C#?

Tags: .net, xpath, cefsharp

.NET C# Programming use CefSharp,
Is there any way to get the xpath of an element with code?
Just click one element in page,then get it's xpath.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the recommended way is to access the DOM is either via JavaScript or ChromeDriver (i.e. Chromium Debug Protocol).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Please elaborate

Comment: After cefsharp loaded one page,I want to click an element in the page  and get the element's xpath. Just like click one inputbox and then display the inputbox's text.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using DevTools for this? Technically it should be possible, likely take some fiddling to implement.